# How to turn string to date using Moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'd like to turn

`2021030213000 +0000`

into this format

`1:00 pm`

I'm using Moment.js in the project and I've tried to do it like so

Moment("2021030213000 +0000").format('LT')

But it returns invalid date.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What does `13000` represent after YYYYMMDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that you are trying to invoke moment("dateStr") where your dateStr is not ISO-8601 compliant.

You can see the relevant API doc here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

You want to use moment's String+Format parser api in order to pass in a different format like the one you have above: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

So for your case, it would look like:

```
moment("2021030213000 +0000", "YYYYMMDDHHmm +ZZ").format("LT")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you could use somethings like this:

```
var date = moment("2021030213000 +0000",  "YYYYMMDDhhmm").format('LT');
console.log(date);
```